# Capacitor charging with a MOSFET

Tags: power

I am facing an issue with capacitive load circuit. I have a circuit which consist PMOS and a capacitor. I want to charge the capacitor within a specific time period and MOSFET should provide a fix amount of current,  and I need to control the gate voltage of PMOS.
Can anyone help me to make a rough schematic of this theme?

Comment: For what purpose? A railgun is very different than a signal circuit.

Comment: All designs must start with input-output specs define range and tolerance . Then purpose and budget

Comment: Charging 1500uF at 1A takes way less than 200ms.

Answer (score 5):

What you’re looking for is a *current source*, which will charge the capacitor with a linear ramp.

More about MOSFET current sources here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-basic-mosfet-constant-current-source/

**Further Reading**

https://www.analog.com/en/app-notes/an-105fa.html

---

Ok, so you've clarified that you want a *maximum* of 1A, with a charge period of 200ms. You've also specified a supply of 30-40V. That makes a huge difference.

What's needed is a *current limiter*, which we can construct from your PMOS high-side switch pretty easily.

Here's how that looks ([simulate it here](https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmATNA7AhAOBjVIAWfbEfckI5cgUwFowwAoAMxFRxw9SJWQBsPPshphoSMAmYAlfkKap5IHJCjqia5Gp1QJzAE7KwnYxiE7oA5gBcOGJWHMdN4Z2sZ64JATlTIwPwEwAWCBAE4QenRwqSIuIgccAQQicMgBBgxwOBAAE1pWAEMAVwAbG2YAd3BwpVReFzUGvkhqpuEOLk62mt41EObXE25ejpHjUzajMDrO2fqHdTB4NoBzWqU0AbnRCyhmDb2UQmVjnXbjpyFObmuDmqvnY8JRtnAiPlvNru40cAkXlQ7QWKGIP22BwAMidflF-t9dDYDCVaJRpj8Wj8JgNVu1%20uBTKCccwAMbKAnHSGWOBSLyQFYCNBSDDaZDhBCzUawBnMWYierdVRwtTI1F6YE1CbfMCfEXMQR3Uwy5WNC7IPgAL1oADtaAZGAMARhZcgEJwFjgVnBUFl1OhVo7HTg%20CtwMxNXCsTLnEptXqDSt8cM5gSsWMriZJm8%20kt7j6LMwAB4cBFLVDhbioLBUD45ABqAB0AM4ALV1%20uYRH8HAQNzr9i%20kEibRT-kF2W0zXSudlIBsAHsS2UAJYAWxHNhL%20bWxeYA44EAErSozZbPLg5gz7JIAVQSBgq3C5jr%20-ti5QIAAwgOdciB2V5%20plyBsppwuvVlvwjuEHuDxuzYngIZ4QBAh7wN%20v7-iAAAO9AAGIAKIAColgACgOVSVgugQgC%20ajvp%20xBcBaZ4QXAx4pCBkgcOAfzXkUsFFKSk4DgY04PjYAD0V4lAYBjMEAA)):

[image]

(Notes: Trigger the one-shot by toggling the input at left. Reset the sim using the 'RESET' button at upper right.)

The PNP senses the current across the 600mOhm resistor. 1A across the sense is 600mV which is about the PNP's Vbe threshold, so any current above that will turn on the PNP and throttle back the p-FET. It's precise enough for this application.

The n-FET is a logic control. I show it being controlled by a 200ms one-shot; I assume this 200ms pulse will come from some controller in your system. If this is for power-on, you could use a reset pulse from a voltage supervisor chip.

In this case, the p-FET has a maximum power dissipation of 30W, and the sense resistor 0.6W. Size accordingly.

One last thing: the Zener diode across the p-FET gate + source limits Vgs to 10V (a common limit for logic-level FETs.) It doesn't conduct until the end of the charge cycle, when cap reaches the power supply voltage and the current drops below 1A.

Comment: Yes I think. MOSFET (either PMOS ot NMOS) (i think PMOS will be better), gate voltage controlled in a manner so that it can provide only 1A current for 200ms. So it can charge the capacitor 1500uf. Question is how to control that gate voltage so mosfet can give only 1A.

Comment: The target is to hold the PMOS in linear region for 200ms. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible: you control the current source. If it’s a small cap, a current mirror can do this. A large one needs a current sense and feedback.

Comment: cap is 1500 uf and it should be charged in 200ms with max 1 A.

Comment: Ok, so we have clarification of *max* of 1A. That's a job for a current limiter.

Comment: If the OP knows the input voltage is 30-40V, would it not be better to increase the current sense resistance so that it produces the desired current at 30V input via V=IR? And then drop any remaining voltage beyond 30V across the PMOS to achieve the desired current? That would stress the PMOS less I would think. Or is something wrong with that approach?

Comment: Oh, I guess the problem with that approach is that as the cap charges up it wouldn't be able to maintain the current.

Comment: I'm interpreting OPs desire to bias the p-MOS to achieve the (now-clarified) *max* charge rate of 1A (don't know why - inrush limiting?) At any rate the cap charges up to 30V in about 40ms. The FET sheds an average of 15W in the process.

Comment: @hacktastical in your schematic you are charging a 1.5mf cap with 1A current? am I right? IN my case, PMOS will be connected to a capacitive load(1500uf). I would like to charge to operate the PMOS only in the linear region and the max drain current will be 1A. So the target is to control the gate of PMOS for 200ms. So consider gate has 5V, coming from controller of my system. So what would you suggest?

Comment: I don't think we need a current limiter. because I am trying to reduce the inrush current. and it's too high. So operating the PMOS in linear region and then turn off the gate.

Comment: A current limiter is exactly what you need, based on your statement about the *maximum* current being 1A. The way the circuit works, the p-FET will be biased in its linear region until the capacitor reaches the supply voltage and the current drops off, at which point it will be fully on until you turn it off.  You can replace the one shot with your logic control signal to control the charging time. It is compatible with 5V or 3.3V logic.

Comment: @hacktastical okay.I got your idea, just one thing. Once the capacitor reached the supply voltage and current drop off, if we turn off the gate. because I don't want to turn on the PMOS completely. Once the capacitor is charged, this precharge path should be off. Then I will turn on my main switch which is in the system. I try to simulate this on LTspcie. Can I apply PWM signal on gate voltage?

Comment: The p-FET will never source more than 1A, so you do not care if it’s turned on harder at the end of the charge. If another load is switched in it will immediately revert to linear mode if the load draws 1A. That’s what a current limiter does. You do not need a PWM to control it, the PNP takes care of that.

Comment: @hacktastical okah thanks for your all kind information. I try to simulate this circuit and will let you know.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: make sure the FET Vgs max isn’t exceeded. This may require some modifications to the circuit.

Comment: Yes, I have to ope such kind of FET which has VGs= +/-40V. As my supply will be 25 to 40V and gate will have 5V signal.

Comment: The Vgs can be limited by making the 10k that connects to the gate into a voltage divider set so that  Vgs will be no more than 10V. You can also use a 10V zener diode to do that.

Comment: I think power dissipation is too high. I have to check SOA of FET also. is 30W allow for 200ms or not.

Comment: That’s the peak dissipation. Average during the charging interval will be half that. Still, the FET will heat some because it’s in linear mode, no avoiding that. Just make sure the FET is big enough and has adequate thermal handing. You can also use multiple FETs in parallel.

Comment: I want to add my simulation here...can you tell me how can add a file here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134566/discussion-between-sikhar-and-hacktastical).

Comment: @hacktastical what if i use NMOS in this case? and working would be same...what essential changed do we need?

Answer (score 4):

Given the silly prices of small, low current op-amps, and how ubiquitous they are, the simplest way is to just use an op amp to control the gate to limit the current to 1A. Alternatively you could use a current limiting switch - also a ubiquitous, cheap chip, but there's no standard pinout nor programming resistor scaling, so you may have a design for a particular chip, but only chips that do the same function but don't have same package or pinout or application schematic would be available for purchase. With a rail-to-rail jellybean op-amp, there's a huge selection, as in this application almost any part will work as long as it's a typical low-voltage CMOS op-amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feBkvS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U1 should be a low-power rail-to-rail in-out type with quiescent current of a couple hundred microamps. It could also be a TL071 if you've got that. D1 is a 5V Zener. A slightly different voltage should be chosen so that between 1-2mA of quiescent current, the voltage is around 5V.

Since the capacitance is known, we don't need to measure the current directly anyway. All we need is to keep the voltage on the capacitor rising at a constant rate. We can take a time derivative of the capacitor voltage, i.e. the slope of the ramp, and the op-amp can regulate the slope and thus the charging current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmwm8f.png)</sup>

D1 limits the supply voltage on the op-amp. The op-amp U1 should be TL071 or another that can take a high supply voltage. The supply voltage regulation could be changed to suit a low-voltage op-amp. The remainder of the circuitry won't have to change.

C3 is the differentiator capacitor. C4 limits the op-amp's bandwith to keep the start-up transient in check. It's unnecessary if U1 were a slow microcurrent type (say 100kHz bandwidth). R8-R9 relax the output range requirement on the op-amp - the "in-regulation" operating voltage is around 1.2V instead of 0.6V. C5 limits the reference voltage rise rate to below that of the differentiator output, so that the current regulation doesn't overshoot.

A simpler differentiator can be made using discrete components. C3 & R2 form the differentiator, Q1 & Q2 are the gain stages, C2 is a compensation capacitor, R1 is Q2's bias, D1+C4 are startup compensation to drive Q2 into conduction and start from zero current instead of maximum current. Q1's Vbe acts as a slope reference voltage.

R3 adjusts the conductance of Q2 and thus the speed and accuracy of the circuit. It should be adjusted down when the circuit is not fast enough - based on transistor types and working voltage. R3 should ideally be a current source, set to about 0.7mA.

This circuit works fairly well and can be adjusted to work great even at low voltages like 5V for USB applications. It's fairly cost-effective, given that these days the cost of a solution is not only the cost of the parts but the cost of a headache when the more specialized parts become unavailable.

If jellybean BJTs and MOSfets become unavailable, there's not much that can be done to help - at that point application-specific parts won't be available either...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP4IOA.png)</sup>